# clustering an image based on RGB and coloring each cluster based on its center

Tags: image-processing, k-means, opencv, python

If I wanted to divide an image into three clusters (for clustering we use K-means algorithm and its features are RGB as said in title.) and each part would be colored as same as its cluster center (for example if its brown then whole cluster should change to brown) what should I do?
thanks in advance for your time.
[painting of an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNXfS.png)

> https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/05/26/opencv-python-k-means-color-clustering/

Comment: The best way would be to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question to show your input image, your expected output image and your latest/greatest attempt at code.

Comment: greetings, the code doesn't necessary interest me, I am wondering more about what is the right way of doing it, but I added an image to show what i mean in the question

Comment: There were 3 parts to my comment. Please try and address all three, rather than just one. Thank you.

Comment: there is no specific picture(take any pic you want). as for the output: there is link in my question of an image divided into three parts(clusters) and the rest is in my Question. as for the code: Coding is not the issue here,finding the best route is. I take it you are familiar with K-means algorithm so, you should know here the cluster centers are colors (because features are RGB) and because we want to color each three part of picture same as cluster center we need coordinates of that center in image.

Comment: but you are right with code this problem is more understandable so I've put a link. its similar to what I want(use of kmeans and its features) it should give you an Idea. thank you for your time.

Comment: I didn't really understand what you want, but consider using `sklearn.cluster.KMeans` function. Thus once your culsters are formed, you can access centers of each labels using `cluster_centers_` and each point associated to each clusters `labels_`. For more info check  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Comment: Hi Skaddd, I am familiar with sklearn that's not the problem here but you can check the link if you haven't already and see an approach which is similar to what I'm saying maybe it'll help you. thank you for your time